# Invalidate OAuth token in Asp.net-Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I want to invalidate the bearer token in Asp.net-Identity. I tried to call the UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId) and I can se that my user's security stamp get updated. But the old tokens are still valid. Does that only invalidate cookie authentication?

Is it possible to solve it in another way?

Comment: I had the same problem and haven't found a good/practical solution yet. One approach is to use a short lifetime for the bearer token itself and increase its lifetime using refresh tokens.

Comment: Could you document how you increase the lifetime. Perhaps that would make a good answer for Rikard to accept. Thanks

Comment: I know how to increase/decrease the lifetime of the token. Thanx

Comment: Have you found any way to do this? In my scenario I would like to invalidate the tokens when users changes their password.

Comment: @MarkVincze no I haven't. The only way to go I think is to revalidate token through refresh_token.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Out of the box it is't possible to invalidate tokens, because they are generated by the server's machinekey.

Answer (score 7):

You could do this by including the SecurityStamp (or some hash of it) in the token. You could then create your own OnReceive handler that verified the SecurityStamp for that user against the database.

The downside to this is you have a database hit for EVERY request, so it removes one of the key benefits of having a bearer token in the first place.

In effect, you would be combining the responsibilities of a bearer token and refresh token into one token.

Using refresh tokens instead, which are submitted much less frequently, will be far more performant, it won't really entail any more coding and it's a fairly widely recognised security flow model.